# XSLT output does not display

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I am a novice to XSLT. I am trying to generate a text file from an XSLT. When I run XSLT against the input XML using **XALAN** parser, the text file generates without an output.

This is the **XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="cities" as="xs:string*">
         <xsl:sequence select="addressbook/address/city" />
         <xsl:sequence select="'Virginia'" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>These are some of the cities:&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$cities" separator="&#xA;" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is the **XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<addressbook>
 <address>
    <name>Peter Thompson</name>
    <stree>3456 South Blvd.</stree>
    <city>Chicago</city>
    <state>IL</state>
    <zip-code>34678</zip-code>
 </address>

 <address>
    <name>Jason Thompson</name>
    <stree>3456 Fort Main</stree>
    <city>South Carolina</city>
    <state>NC</state>
    <zip-code>67878</zip-code>
 </address>
```

I try to compile it in this way:

```
java -classpath ~/Downloads/xalan/xalan.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in cities.xml -xsl cities.xsl -out citiesop.txt
```

The `cities.txt` file is generated with just the output:

> These are some of the cities.

Please assist me to understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Xalan only supports XSLT 1.0. Due to `version="2.0"` it uses relaxed rules for syntax checking and simply ignores the `<xsl:sequence>` elements. Therefore your variable `cities` is empty.

For this stylesheet you need to use a XSLT 2.0 engine, like Saxon.

Comment: Or simply change version tag to 1.0 and namespace accordingly. I dont see any xslt2-specific instruction there

Comment: @AydinK.`xsl:sequence` and `xsl:value-of@separator` and `xsl:variable@as`

Comment: This doesn't seem correct forwards-compatible behaviour. When a 1.0 processor running a 2.0 stylesheet sees an unknown attribute (like @as) it should ignore it, but when it attempts to execute an unknown element (like xsl:sequence) it should throw an error. Ah well, I guess it won't be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite it in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>These are some of the cities:&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="addressbook/address/city" >
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>Virginia</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. South Carolina and Virginia are *states*, not *cities*.

Comment: Hi All .. Thank you so much for your comments. I have used Saxon and this has worked. I have understood that the version was the issue!